# Manage user interaction with Express application

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, express, url-routing

I am fairly new to Express. In this case I have a `<table>` in the page `users` in which I have one link in each row to delete the entry. Every time the user click on these links I have to delete that entry in the database. This is not a SPA and I do not (want to) use other front end frameworks like React.

What is the best way to deal with this?

The way I was dealing with it was creating a new route:

```
router.get('/users/delete/:userId', db.deleteUser(req.query.deleteUser));
```

And the in the front end at the end of every row:

```
<a href="users/delete/deleteuser=77">Delete this user</a>
```

But it does not seem the best way to go about this. I thought about using AJAX but I found it a bit of a overhead to create a hidden input and a for for each row of my table. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete in router like below

Server-side

```
router.delete('/users/:userId(\\d+)', deleteUser);
... 
function deleteUser(req, res, next) {
    db.deleteUser(req.params.userId, function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).send(err.message);

        res.status(200).end(); 
    });
}
```

Client-side

```
<a onclick="deleteUser(77)">Delete this user</a>
...
function deleteUser(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/users/' + id,
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = '/users';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what if in the same page i have two icons one to delete say the user and one to delete a connection of the user? can this method scale?

Comment: You can create separate router to delete user and connection. e.g `router.delete('/users/:id')` and `router.delete('/users/:id/connection')`. Why not?